# Is there a quick way to let R know your variables are categorical in lm regression?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

Let's say you have a categorical variable but the categories are numbers.  Is there a way to within the lm() formula, let R know that a specific regressor is categorical not numerical?

Thanks!

Comment: isn't this unnecessary? my memory is you don't need to specify

Comment: How about `as.factor()`?

Comment: Yes, make them factors within your data frame, or wrap them each in `as.factor` inside your formula. But if you're trying to shortcut it like `lm(y ~ ., data = df)`, make those columns factors in your df first

Comment: @MikePalmice Their categories are numbers so it will treat them as continuous if you don't specify to treat them as categories by converting to a factor.

Comment: If the categorical variables are binary then you get the same model.matrix whether they are factor or numeric.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.